# 'tuple' object is not callable for @renderer_classes((JSONRenderer,))

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I got

```
'tuple' object is not callable
```

error when using `@renderer_classes((JSONRenderer,))` decorators for function. Any idea??

Comment: Please show the full traceback.